# GameObject doesn't appear after it disappears in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in Unity and C#. I tried building a basic game where the GameObject's presence in the scene is toggled when a key is pressed. The GameObject does disappear when I press "Space", but it never appears when I press the same key again. The following is the code.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
        private GameObject aj;
        private bool flag = true;

        void Start () {
            aj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("robo");
        }

        void Update () {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                flag = !flag;
                aj.SetActive(flag);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know where the error lies.

Comment: Assuming that this script is on the gameobject, you're disabling the script that's running when you're deactivating the gameobject. You should put this script on some sort of manager so that it doesn't get disabled when the gameobject does.

Comment: It works. I created a parent GameObject and added the current  GameObject to it. But I noticed that the GameObject flickers and it doesn't always disappear and appear right after I press the key, any suggestions on why this happens?

Comment: Because you're checking for space to be pressed every frame so it's trying to flip it every frame. Use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))` instead. This will only check on the first frame it's pushed.

Comment: It helped me fix the issue. Can I make your comment as the answer for the question I posted?

Comment: I'll post it as answer, give me a couple of minutes :) EDIT: posted as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as answer for future viewers:

The main reason that the gameobject doesn't reappear is because when you turn off the object, the script attached to it is disabled as well. In order to fix this, you must have the script to disable it, on a different object. I usually use a manager object which is just an empty gameobject with scripts on it.

A secondary issue in your code is that you're using `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))` in update which will try to change it every frame. Change it to `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))` to have it only be true on the first frame pressed.

Answer (score 1):

From a first view the code seems correctly, the only problem that I could figure it out is that you disable the object where the script is placed or his parent, and so the script won't be executed the second time.

P.s. I recommend you to not use that "flag" variable, instead would be more precise to use the GameObject.activeSelf attribute.

Comment: I modified the code by using aj.SetActive(true). It works now.